# Which cast am I using?

Tags: c++, casting

I'm trying to cast away const from an object but it doesn't work. But if I use old C-way of casting code compiles. So which casting I'm suppose to use to achieve this same effect? I wouldn't like to cast the old way.

```
//file IntSet.h

#include "stdafx.h"
#pragma once
/*Class representing set of integers*/
template<class T>
class IntSet
{
private:
    T** myData_;
    std::size_t mySize_;
    std::size_t myIndex_;
public:
#pragma region ctor/dtor
    explicit IntSet();
    virtual ~IntSet();
#pragma endregion
#pragma region publicInterface
    IntSet makeUnion(const IntSet&)const;
    IntSet makeIntersection(const IntSet&)const;
    IntSet makeSymmetricDifference(const IntSet&)const;
    void insert(const T&);

#pragma endregion
};

//file IntSet_impl.h

#include "StdAfx.h"
#include "IntSet.h"

#pragma region ctor/dtor
template<class T>
IntSet<T>::IntSet():myData_(nullptr),
                    mySize_(0),
                    myIndex_(0)
{
}

IntSet<T>::~IntSet()
{
}
#pragma endregion

#pragma region publicInterface
template<class T>
void IntSet<T>::insert(const T& obj)
{
    /*Check if we are initialized*/
    if (mySize_ == 0)
    {
        mySize_ = 1;
        myData_ = new T*[mySize_];
    }
    /*Check if we have place to insert obj in.*/
    if (myIndex_ < mySize_)
    {//IS IT SAFE TO INCREMENT myIndex while assigning?
        myData_[myIndex_++] = &T(obj);//IF I DO IT THE OLD WAY IT WORKS
        return;
    }

    /*We didn't have enough place...*/
    T** tmp = new T*[mySize_];//for copying old to temporary basket
    std::copy(&myData_[0],&myData_[mySize_],&tmp[0]);

}
#pragma endregion
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a dedicated C++ casting operator for dealing with const: `const_cast`:

```
myData_[myIndex_++] = &const_cast<T>(obj);
```

Comment: ...you probably want to write that as `&const_cast<T&>(obj);` or, even better, directly as `const_cast<T*>(&obj);`

Comment: It would be more correct to remove `const` from the argument declaration.

Comment: Dzięki Michał. Głowę bym sobie dał uciąć, że tak właśnie próbowałem to zrobić parę minut temu i dostawałem błąd compilatora, dlatego też postanowiłem się kogoś spytać co robię nie tak.

Comment: @Potatoswatter - could you elaborate on that please?

Comment: @Vlad I absolutely love your example.

Comment: Firstly, `const_cast<T>` is illegal if `T` is not a pointer or refernce type. `const_cast` can only be used to cast to pointer or reference types. Secondly, applying `&` to the result of the cast is illegal since it is not an lvalue (unless `T` is a reference type).

Answer (score 2):

I assume that this is what you're referring to:

```
    myData_[myIndex_++] = &T(obj);//IF I DO IT THE OLD WAY IT WORKS
```

This is not a cast expression. `T(obj)` constructs a temporary object and `&` takes the address of it, which is illegal. You can't store a pointer to a temporary because it vanishes when execution gets to the next `;`.

The issue here is not casting but rather how your structure fundamentally stores data. Do you want to make a modifiable copy, owned by the structure? Or do you want to refer to external data which is managed by something else?

If you want the structure to actually contain the data it returns, you could do something like

```
    myData_[myIndex_++] = new T(obj);
```

(But remember to `delete` later.) If you want to reference external data, and yet be able to modify it, you want

```
void IntSet<T>::insert(T& obj) // remove const
```

If you want to have non-modifiable references to external data, then

```
T const ** myData_;
```

will remove the need to remove const-ness. (But note that this would allow things like `insert(3)` to crash the program.)

## However

You would be much better off just using C++'s built-in tools. Instead of implementing `IntSet` with `MakeUnion`, `makeIntersection`, and `makeSymmetricDifference`, use a sorted `std::vector<int>` and/or `std::set<int>` with `std::set_union`, `std::set_intersection`, and `std::set_symmetric_difference`.

Comment: @Potatoswatter I'm still doing my excersises from TC++PL that's why I'm doing everything "by hand". Thanks for advice anyway ;)

Comment: Actually, `T(obj)` *is* a cast expression. This is a functional-style cast. In fact, all expressions of the form `TYPE(<arguments>)` are functional-style casts in C++, even if they have zero or more than one argument.

Comment: @Andrey: Does the standard refer to it as a cast? I see it described as "Explicit type conversion (functional notation)." Considering that it always constructs an object, "cast" doesn't seem an apt description.

Comment: I mean, `T x; … T(x) …` will call the copy constructor rather than do nothing. Does copy elision even apply?

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't the cast.  If you really intend to store a constant object, then declare your array accordingly, e.g.:

```
T const ** myData_;
```

If that's not possible because you actually need to modify the data later, you should then make copy of the argument or reexamine your interface since right now it says you won't be modifying the argument.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want to do this? Why are you storing a pointer to integers passed in instead of the integer itself?

You have a strong possibility of storing a pointer to a temporary; `const T& obj` can be created as a temporary from a type that is convertable to `T`. For example, if you had the following:

```
IntSet<int> int_set;
int_set.insert(1);
short foo= 2;
int_set.insert(foo);
```

Both calls to `IntSet<T>::insert` will result in storing a pointer to a temporary value, which is almost always a bug.

Answer (score -1):

What's wrong with the following function?

int * foo() { int x = 3; return &x; }

Where does x exist? When foo returns what happens to x? I think you need to learn the basics before you start going wild with templates and generic programming.